# How do we get this equation?

Tags: numerical-methods

Given the problem $$-u''(x)+q(x)u(x)=f(x), 0 \leq x \leq 1, \\ u'(0)=u(0), \ \ u(1)=0$$ where $f,g$ are continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with $q(x) \geq q_0>0, x \in [0,1]$. Let $U_j$ be the approximations of $u(x_j)$ at the points $x_j=jh, j=0, 1, \dots , N+1$, where $(N+1)h=1$, that gives the finite difference method $$-\frac{1}{h^2}\left (U_{j-1}-2U_j+U_{j+1}\right )+q(x_j)U_j=f(x_j), \ \ 1 \leq j \leq N \\ \frac{1}{h}(U_1-U_0)-U_0=\frac{1}{2}h\left (q(x_0)U_0-f(x_0)\right )$$ where $U_{N+1}=0$.

I have to justify the form of the equation for the unknown $U_0$.

We have that the approximation of the first derivative $u'(x_j)$ is $$u'(x_j) \approx \frac{u(x_{i+1})-u(x_{i-1})}{2h}$$

so from $u'(0)=u(0)$ we have $$\frac{U_1-U_0}{h}=U_0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{h}(U_1-U_0)-U_0=0$$ but this is not the desired result.

What have I done wrong? How do we get $\frac{1}{h}(U_1-U_0)-U_0=\frac{1}{2}h\left (q(x_0)U_0-f(x_0)\right )$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Introducing the artificial value $U_{-1}$ you get from the boundary equation
$$
\frac{U_1-U_{-1}}{2h}-U_0=0
$$
and from the differential equation
$$
\frac{U_1-2U_0+U_{-2}}{2h}=\frac h2(q(x_0)U_0−f(x_0))
$$
Adding both equations to eliminate $U_{-1}$ gives the presented discretized boundary equation.